# How to show measured distance in screenshot?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I'm trying to take a snapshot with markup and measured distance, but the distance label disappear on the snapshot. How to fix this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Measure extension currently does not support rendering its elements into screenshots. The blue line representing the actual measurement is a 3D element so it does get included in the screenshot, but the little circles and the label are actually HTML elements in an overlay.

EDIT:

Here's an idea for a quick hack. When generating the screenshot I get the list of all the DOM elements that contain length measurement values, and I draw them into the screenshot as simple strings:

```js
function generateScreenshot(viewer) {
    const screenshot = new Image();
    screenshot.onload = function () {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = viewer.container.clientWidth;
        canvas.height = viewer.container.clientHeight;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(screenshot, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // Render measurement labels into the screenshot
        const viewerRect = viewer.container.getBoundingClientRect();
        for (const label of document.querySelectorAll('.measure-length-text')) {
            const labelRect = label.getBoundingClientRect();
            ctx.fillText(
                label.textContent,
                labelRect.x - viewerRect.x,
                labelRect.y - viewerRect.y
            );
        }

        download(canvas.toDataURL(), 'screenshot.png');
    };
    viewer.getScreenShot(viewer.container.clientWidth, viewer.container.clientHeight, function (blob) {
        screenshot.src = blob;
    });
}
```

Comment: What you _could_ try is locating the HTML overlay with the measurement labels, and render it into the screenshot yourself.

Comment: wow, great! It works out! The text position is little bit drifted from the original point, but it's not a deal.

Comment: Hi, Petr. Could you give me any advice about this question if possible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76080606/how-to-change-the-default-up-orientation-and-set-z-axis-upward