# How to change the default up orientation and set z axis upward?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

In Autodesk Service Platform, Y axis is upward in the default orientation. I would like to set z axis upward in the default orientation. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The `Navigation` class provides a method called `setWorldUpVector` that might help here. Here's the method signature:

```js
/**
 * Change the current world up direction.
 *
 *  @param {THREE.Vector3} up - the new world up direction
 *  @param {boolean} reorient - if true, make sure the camera up is oriented towards the world up direction.
 *  @param {boolean} force - if true, will set the new direction regardless of navigation lock
 */
Navigation.prototype.setWorldUpVector = function(up, reorient, force) {...}
```

After loading your model, try adjusting the world up vector like so:

```js
viewer.navigation.setWorldUpVector(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1), true, true);
```